# Double Clicking on row and getting respective row values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, gridview, blazor

[image]

I want to double click on any row to getting respective row values. It is an .Razor page.

Comment: Add code in `code sections` instead of images and show/describe what you tried.

Comment: Besides, it seems you use the third party library? What is your QuickGrid component here?

Comment: @Rena It is a new component built by the Blazor Team in .Net 7.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would create a component that will inherit from QuickGrid, so you can manage it easier in the future.

```
// CustomGrid.razor.cs 
[CascadingTypeParameter( nameof(TGridItem) )]
public partial class CustomGrid<TGridItem> : QuickGrid<TGridItem>, IAsyncDisposable
{
    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JS { get; set; } // inject service in order to use JS interop
   
    // sometimes it is mandatory to override base class parameters by your own
}

// CustomGrid.razor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid // move it into the _Imports.razor 

@typeparam TGridItem // QuickGrid is a generic-typed component
@inherits QuickGrid<TGridItem> // show inheritance 

<div @ref="@_gridRef"> // HTML reference of current element
    <QuickGrid TGridItem="TGridItem"
               Items="@Items"
               ItemsProvider="@ItemsProvider"
               ChildContent="@ChildContent"
               Class="@Class"
               // more parameters... >      
    </QuickGrid>
</div>
```

Since there is no built-in functionality for adding your custom logic into QuickGrid, you will need to use some JavaScript interopability. Read about it more in docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pass-a-dotnetobjectreference-to-an-individual-javascript-function).

We need to declare some local variables in our `CustomGrid.razor.cs`:

```
private string? _rowValue; // specifies row value of currently double clicked row
private ElementReference _gridRef; // HTML element reference object that will be passed to JS function
private IJSObjectReference? _module; // JS module, a file that contains our JS functions

private DotNetObjectReference<CustomGrid<TGridItem>>? _objRef; // .NET object reference that will be passed to JS function in order to use its C# methods
```

And override some of the component lifecycle methods:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    _objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create( this ); // creates .NET object reference of current component instance
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync( bool firstRender )
{
    if( firstRender )
    {
        _module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>( "import", "./js/customGrid.js" ); // creates a reference of our JS module

        if( _module is not null )
        {
            await _module.InvokeVoidAsync( "initialize", _gridRef, _objRef ); // calls our JS function and passes some arguments
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you need to create a JS module and a functions that will add desired logic for you on the first render of the `CustomGrid` component, like this:

```
// wwwroot/js/customGrid.js
export function initialize(customGrid, dotNetObj) {
    if (customGrid) { // check if custom grid element exists
        var rowValue;
        const rows = customGrid.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr'); // get all rows except the header row  

        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].addEventListener('dblclick', (e) => { // add event listener to current row in the loop
                rowValue = e.path[1].innerText; // get innerText of current row in the loop
                console.log(rowValue)

                updateCurrentRowValue(rowValue, dotNetObj); // function that will return the current row value and refresh the UI
            });
        }
    }
}

function updateCurrentRowValue(rowValue, dotNetObj) {
    dotNetObj.invokeMethodAsync("UpdateCurrentRowValue", rowValue); // C# method 
}
```

We're almost done here! If you would try to perform double click on the row, you would see an error in the console stating that `CustomGrid` does not contain a public method called `UpdateCurrentRowValue`. Let's add it like this:

```
[JSInvokable]
public void UpdateCurrentRowValue( string rowValue )
{
    _rowValue = rowValue; // assign received rowValue from the JS function to our local _rowValue variable
    StateHasChanged(); // force UI refresh
}
```

Now, all you need to do is to display your `_rowValue`:

```
// CustomGrid.razor
<div @ref="@_gridRef">
    <QuickGrid TGridItem="TGridItem" . . . /> // collapsed for brevity

    <p>Current Row Value: @_rowValue</p>
</div>
```

You will also need to `Dispose` your newly created objects of `_module` and `_objRef` using `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync` method:

```
// CustomGrid.razor.cs
async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
{
    if( _module is not null )
    {
        await _module.DisposeAsync();
    }

    _objRef?.Dispose();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<CustomGrid Items="@people">
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.PersonId)" Sortable="true" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.Name)" Sortable="true" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.BirthDate)" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" Sortable="true" />
</CustomGrid>
```

That should work. If you will need any help -- don't hesitate to ask!

**Remarks:**

This is a basic implementation of your request. It doesn't support scenarios when there are more than 1 grid on the page. It might work, but will be buggy, I guess. For that, you will need to add some more code in JS and `CustomGrid` code-behind. I didn't add it because it would be too much code in one answer (quite a lot of code came out here anyway).

**UPD-1:**

Removed custom `[Parameter]s` to override `QuickGrid`'s ones and added a comment.